# Did I differentiate this correctly: $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

> Calculate the first derivative of the function $f: \mathbb{R}
> \setminus \left \{ \frac{-d}{c} \right \} \ni x \mapsto
> \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, c \neq
> 0$

$$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{(a \cdot (cx+d))-((ax+b) \cdot c)}{(cx+d)^{2}}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{acx+ad-(acx+bc)}{(cx+d)^{2}}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{acx+ad-acx-bc}{(cx+d)^{2}}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^{2}}$$

---

I have tried to check my solution with an online... derivator (do you say that?) but its solution was same like mine just with a negative sign which made me feel a bit insecure, that's why I'm asking here if I did it right?

Comment: It looks correct to me...

Comment: First, the verb is "to differentiate" ;). Then yes, it is correct!

Comment: It seems to be correct!

Comment: Yes, your differentiation is correct. If you want to learn more about that function it is called the 'Möbius transformation' (you can google it) and it is very important when it is defined in the complex plane.